# Is it possible to split X-Axis labels into two levels?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, visualization

My X-axis labels are strings and rotating them is making my plot look ugly. In ggplot, is there a way to split up the X-axis labels such that half of them appear on the top and half on the bottom (alternating style). So instead of:

```
Label1 Label2 Label3 Label4
```

I want:

```
Label1   Label3
    Label2    Label4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always prepend the x axis values with alternating newline characters:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c('Label1','\nLabel2','Label3','\nLabel4'),y = 1:4)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()
```

which produces this:

[image]

As a side note, I thought that perhaps you could pass a vector of values to `vjust` in `opts`, but that didn't seem to work. It might in the development version though.

Comment: Thank you. I wish there was an easy way to do this. I deal with long text labels and it becomes a nightmare to do this in an automated way :)

Comment: Coming to an automated way, is there any way to do this for arbitrary data frames without having to manually using `\n` all the time? Thank You!

Comment: @Legend Well, adding `\n` to every other label is vectorizable, so in principle that is only one line to add, using `paste`. More generally, the reason ggplot can't 'auto-magically' do stuff like this is that its impossible to devise a perfectly general solution that handles every possible set of text labels. Oh, and you're welcome! :)